# How to count number characters of strings without using strlen

Tags: c, counting, strlen

I have the task to count the number of letters in random words until "End" is entered. I'm not allowed to use the strlen(); function. That's my solution so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringLength(char string[]){
    unsigned int length = sizeof(*string) / sizeof(char);
    return length;
}

int main(){
    char input[40];
    
    while (strcmp(input, "End") != 0) {
        printf("Please enter characters.\n");
        scanf("%s", &input[0]);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("You've entered the following %s. Your input has a length of %d characters.\n", input, stringLength(input));
    }
}
```

The stringLength value isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `*string` is a single character, so `sizeof(*string)` is the size of one character, which is always `1`.

Comment: You need to write a loop that counts characters until it gets to the null terminator.

Comment: A pointer is not an array is not a pointer.

Comment: increment an integer inside  while (strcmp(input, "End") != 0) {} would do the trick

Comment: The way C (`%s`, `strlen`, and co.) determine if a string has terminated is to continue reading a `char` at a time until `\0` (the null terminator) is encountered. Change your function to do the same.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is expecting `sizeof` to do something other than tell you the number of bytes a particular variable takes up. (In `stringLength` `string` is a `char*` so `*string` is a `char` and occupies one byte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%n` specifier could also be used to capture the number of characters.
Using `%39s` will prevent writing too many characters into the array `input[40]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void)
{
    char input[40] = {'\0'};
    int count = 0;

    do {
        printf("Please enter characters or End to quit.\n");
        scanf("%39s%n", input, &count);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("You've entered the following %s. Your input has a length of %d characters.\n", input, count);
    } while (strcmp(input, "End") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT to correct flaw pointed out by @chux.
using `" %n` to record leading space and `%n"` record total characters this should record the number of leading whitespace and the total characters parsed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char input[40] = {'\0'};
    int count = 0;
    int leading = 0;

    do {
        printf("Please enter characters. Enter End to quit.\n");
        if ( ( scanf(" %n%39s%n", &leading, input, &count)) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("You've entered %s, with a length of %d characters.\n", input, count - leading);
    } while (strcmp(input, "End") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT `stringLength()` function to return length

```
int stringLength(char string[]){
    unsigned int length = 0;
    while ( string[length]) {// true until string[length] is '\0'
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Could you also add a solution for the way the other described? :-)

Comment: `"%n"` will report the number of `char` parsed, including leading white-spaces.  Try entering `" 123"` and output will say the input was `"123"` with length 4.

Comment: Thank you! Question: Why is `while ( string[length] != '\0' )` equal to `while ( string[length] )` ?

Comment: Because the condition is always >= 1 except when it reaches '\0', then it's 0 and breaks. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `sizeof` is evaluated at *compile time*. So it can't be used to determine the length of a string in *run time*.

The length of a string is the number of characters until you encounter a null-character. The size of a string is thus one more than the number of characters. This final null-character is called the *terminating null character*.

So to know the length of a string in run-time, you have to count the number of characters until you encounter a null-character.

Programming this in C is simple; I leave this to you.